# Deploying NodeJS React project on LAMP server

Tags: node.js, apache, reactjs, lamp

I have been developing a web application (as part of a project in my institute) using NodeJS, MongoDB (Mongoose) and React. In the architecture I have an API server made using NodeJS and the database is stored locally in my machine. Also, I have a React project (independent of the NodeJS server). I am using APIs to get information from the node server into React application. My NodeJS app is deployed at localhost:4000 and react website on localhost:3000 Now I have to push this project to production.

I have been given a server to SSH into and deploy the website. The server is an Apache server and in its root a WordPress site has been installed. I have been asked to deploy the website at the URL Somedomain.com/ProjectName . With my current understand of the state, I would have to create a subfolder with the Project's Name and serve the site content from there. Though I have deployed NodeJS apps remotely on NodeJS hosts, I have no experience with above cases.

How should I proceed with this? What would be the fastest approach to tackle this as I have a time constraint.